# Is there away for an HTML content block to render different images based on device used to display email?

Tags: marketing-cloud

**First Question:**

There are two images that needed to be rendered in Salesforce Marketing Cloud based on where they're being viewed from (Smartphone device or desktop).

I wrote a script in HTML file in a content block, which will return an image (refered by *ContentBlockbyKey*)  if displayed from a mobile device or else another image if displayed from desktop. However, image is not being rendered:

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Mobile Test</title>
</head>
<body>

 <p id="text"></p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  var element = document.getElementById('text');
  if (isMobile) {
     contentblockbykey("4c824534-5e58-4003-99b3-716ccb7c8ba1")
  } else {
   contentblockbykey("95198c2a-2eb6-40e1-b3dc-4dae980d7c96")
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second Question:**

Is it possible to know which device is the email being viewed from using Ampscript?

Comment: This is a css question and belongs on Stack Overflow as this is unrelated to SalesForce

Comment: @Gortonington - thank you, i'll post it there.

Comment: @Gortonington - i've updated my question, please review and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMPscript and SSJS are both server-side meaning they are run and processed prior to the email being sent. Anything 'client-side' would have to be done via CSS or 'live images' such as Movable ink or Live Clicker.

Comment: I went ahead and used CSS. Here is my HTML content block with CSS: <picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="http://image.email.bxyz.com/lib/fe991274746d77/m/17/d8efa3cc-4012-4901-9853-81a5a162760c.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="http://image.email.bxyz.com/lib/fe991274746207d77/m/17/c8503c85-f099-4c19-8b60-1f7e23b2c60c.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://image.email.bxyz.com/lib/fe9912474620d77/m/17/c8503c85-f099-4c19-8b60-1f7e23b2c60c.jpg" alt="Welcome_Mobile" style="width:auto;">
  
</picture>

Comment: The code is defaulting to only the image specified in <img src> tag, but not the rest when the device changed? Do you know as to why that might be the cause?